# How to get the full path of a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I have create a directory name 'DbInventory' in E drive of my machine
Now in my c# application I want to get the full path of this directoty(DbInventory).

bellow I am mentioning the code I have used

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("DbInventory");
string currentDirectoryName = info.FullName;
```

But this currentDirectoryName  string return the file location in C drive.

Comment: Why you are sure that application will look for directory on E drive instead of directory on C drive?

Comment: at a guess... does the C drive location include `bin/debug`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.directoryinfo.aspx) constructor takes parameter as a string with *full path*. When you just write a folder name, it gets the location of your Visual Studio's default path which is most common in your `C:/` drive and under `Bin/Debug` folder.

So in my computer, your `currentDirectoryName` will be;

```
C:\Users\N53458\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\1\1\bin\Debug\DbInventory
```

If you want to get full path name, you can use [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) method;

> Returns the directory information for the specified path string.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating with the

```
new DirectoryInfo("DbInventory");
```

a new directory on the default drive (C). Take a look at:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx)

If you want to get the directory info object of the already created one on drive E you have to specify the path.

Comment: I agree with you but then if OP has the full path then OP won't need to use directory info at all :) +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Path.GetDirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("DbInventory");
string currentDirectoryName = info.FullName;
string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

try server.mappath

```
string currentDirectoryName =Server.MapPath(info.FullName);
```

hope this will work for you